# WPF datagrid, autocompletebox cell

Tags: wpf, datagrid, autocomplete

I have a datagrid in which a AutoCompleteBox
I want when I switch the focus to the cell containing the ACB, it goes directly to input mode. Currently I have to press the enter key to make it. 
here the code :

```
   <DataGrid Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                RowHeight="30"
                Grid.Column="0" 
                SelectionUnit="Cell"
                ItemsSource="{Binding  RowsToEdit, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" 

                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
                b:DataGridEnterKeyBehavior.EnterKeyNexCellProperty="True"
                b:DataGridEnterEditOnCellGotFocus.EnterEditOnGotFocusProperty="True" Margin="0,45,0,5" Grid.RowSpan="2"

              >


        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Code, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,  Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat=\{0:#\}}"  Header="Code" >
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewKeyDown">
                        <gs:EventToCommand Command="{Binding HandleCellKeyDownCommand, Source={StaticResource MyViewModel}}"
                                           PassEventArgsToCommand="True"

                                           />
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name" >

                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Nom}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <!--FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" -->
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>

                        <controls:AutoCompleteBox
                                x:Name="acb2"
                                Text="{Binding Nom, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                ItemsSource="{Binding Names,Source={StaticResource MyViewModel}}" 
                                SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedPerson, Source={StaticResource MyViewModel}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                ValueMemberBinding="{Binding Nom}"
                                Style="{StaticResource acbStyle}"
                                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource AutoCompleteBoxItemTemplate}"

                                >
                            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                                    <gs:EventToCommand Command="{Binding SelectionChangedCommand, Source={StaticResource MyViewModel}}" 
                                           CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedPerson, Source={StaticResource MyViewModel}}"
                                           />
                                </i:EventTrigger>
                            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        </controls:AutoCompleteBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>

            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Adresse, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"       Header="Adresse" />

        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>




//Behaviors
    //Behavior for passing automatically in edit mode when cell get focus
  public static class DataGridEnterEditOnCellGotFocus
{


    public static readonly DependencyProperty EnterEditOnGotFocusProperty =
     DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("EnterEditOnGotFocus",
     typeof(bool),
     typeof(DataGridEnterEditOnCellGotFocus),
     new UIPropertyMetadata(false, ProcessCellGotFocusEnter));



    public static bool GetEnterEditOnGotFocusProperty(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(EnterEditOnGotFocusProperty);
    }

    public static void SetEnterEditOnGotFocusProperty(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(EnterEditOnGotFocusProperty, value);
    }



    private static void ProcessCellGotFocusEnter(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGrid dg = (d as DataGrid);

        if (dg != null)
        {
            if ((bool)e.NewValue)
                dg.GotFocus += dg_GotFocus;
            else
                dg.GotFocus -= dg_GotFocus;
        }
    }


    private static void dg_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


        if (e.OriginalSource.GetType() == typeof(DataGridCell))
        {

            DataGridCell source = e.OriginalSource as DataGridCell;

            DataGrid grd = (DataGrid)sender;
            grd.BeginEdit(e);

            Control control = GetFirstChildByType<Control>(source);
            if (control != null)
            {

                control.Focus();

             }
        }
    }

//Behaviors for moving from cell to another with entre key
public static class DataGridEnterKeyBehavior
{


    public static readonly DependencyProperty EnterKeyNexCellProperty =
     DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("EnterKeyNexCell",
     typeof(bool),
     typeof(DataGridEnterKeyBehavior),
     new UIPropertyMetadata(false, ProcessEnterKeyDown));



    public static bool GetEnterKeyNexCellProperty(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(EnterKeyNexCellProperty);
    }

    public static void SetEnterKeyNexCellProperty(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(EnterKeyNexCellProperty, value);
    }



    private static void ProcessEnterKeyDown(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGrid dg = (d as DataGrid);

        if (dg != null)
        {
            if ((bool)e.NewValue)
                dg.PreviewKeyDown += dg_PreviewKeyDownDatagrid;
            else
                dg.PreviewKeyDown -= dg_PreviewKeyDownDatagrid;
        }
    }


    private static void dg_PreviewKeyDownDatagrid(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

        DataGrid dg = (sender as DataGrid);

        var uiElement = e.OriginalSource as UIElement;
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter && uiElement != null)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            dg.SelectedCells.Clear();
            uiElement.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
            dg.BeginEdit();

        }

    }
}
```

And the ViewModel

```
public class MyViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    ObservableCollection<Person> _names = null;
    ObservableCollection<Person> _rowsToEdit = null;

    public ObservableCollection<Person> RowsToEdit
    {
        get { return _rowsToEdit; }
        set
        {
            _rowsToEdit = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("RowsToEdit");
        }
    }

    RelayCommand _loadClients;
    RelayCommand _showSelectedPerson;
    RelayCommand<Person> _selectchangedcommand;
    RelayCommand<KeyEventArgs> _handleCellKeyDown;

    Person _selectedPerson;




    public Person SelectedPerson
    {
        get { return _selectedPerson; }
        set
        {
            _selectedPerson = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedPerson");
        }
    }



    public ObservableCollection<Person> Names
    {
        get { return _names; }
        set
        {
            _names = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Names");
        }
    }




    public RelayCommand LoadClientCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_loadClients == null)
                _loadClients = new RelayCommand(LoadCommandExecute);
            return _loadClients;
        }
    }



    private void LoadCommandExecute()
    {
        LoadClients();
        List<Person> ll = new List<Person>(1);
        ll.Add(new Person(0, "", ""));
        RowsToEdit = new ObservableCollection<Person>(ll);
    }



    public void LoadClients()
    {
        List<Person> ll = new List<Person>(8);
        ll.Add(new Person(1, "AAAAAAA", "Adresse1"));
        ll.Add(new Person(2, "AABBBBB", "Adresse 2"));
        ll.Add(new Person(3, "AAACCCC", "Adresse3"));
        ll.Add(new Person(4, "BBBBHHHH", "Adresse4"));
        ll.Add(new Person(5, "BBBCGGFR", "Adresse5"));
        ll.Add(new Person(6, "JJJJJHHGYGH", "Adresse6"));
        ll.Add(new Person(7, "HHHHHHHHGGG", "Adresse7"));
        ll.Add(new Person(8, "AAAAHHGBV", "Adresse8"));

        Names = new ObservableCollection<Person>(ll);

    }



    public RelayCommand ShowSelectedPersonCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_showSelectedPerson == null)
                _showSelectedPerson = new RelayCommand(ShowSelectedPersonCommandExecute);
            return _showSelectedPerson;
        }
    }



    private void ShowSelectedPersonCommandExecute()
    {
        if (SelectedPerson != null)
            MessageBox.Show(SelectedPerson.Nom);
        else
            MessageBox.Show("No sslections.");

    }


    public RelayCommand<Person> SelectionChangedCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_selectchangedcommand == null)
                _selectchangedcommand = new RelayCommand<Person>(SelectionChangedCommandExecute);
            return _selectchangedcommand;
        }
    }


    private void SelectionChangedCommandExecute(Person SelectedPerson)
    {
        /*if (SelectedPerson != null)
            MessageBox.Show(SelectedPerson.Code.ToString());
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Pas de sélection.");
        */

    }


  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found a solution, Perhaps there were other better. 
the problem lies in the selection of control "Text" inside the ACB. So change the behavior as follows solve the problem. Here The code :

```
   private static void dg_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


        if (e.OriginalSource.GetType() == typeof(DataGridCell))
        {
            // Starts the Edit on the row;
            DataGridCell source = e.OriginalSource as DataGridCell;


            DataGrid grd = (DataGrid)sender;

            grd.BeginEdit(e);

            source.IsEditing = true;

            Control control = GetFirstChildByType<Control>(source);
            if (control != null)
            {
                //Here i Check if control is an ACB, if it is
               //Try to access to Control "Text" inside it and that's all
                if (control.GetType() == typeof(AutoCompleteBox))
                {
                    control = GetFirstChildByType<Control>(control);
                }

            }
          if (control != null)
                control.Focus();


            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to handle PreviewGotFocus of your datagrid.
2. You have to use DataGrid:BeginEdit() to enter editing mode.
3. We find next cell in current row to move further when ENTER is pressed.
4. Once we reach last cell of current row, pressing ENTER move focus to next row's first cell.
5. Once we last cell of last row, pressing ENTER move focus to first row's first cell.

See example below. It uses a DataGrid named dgrdInvoice.

```
 private void dgrdInvoice_PreviewGotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.OriginalSource is DataGridCell)
        {               
            DataGridCell cell = (DataGridCell)e.OriginalSource;

            Debug.WriteLine(cell.ToString());

            RoutedEventHandler gotFocusHandler = new RoutedEventHandler(DataGridCell_GotFocus);
            cell.GotFocus -= gotFocusHandler;
            cell.GotFocus += gotFocusHandler;

            KeyEventHandler previewKeyDownHandler = new KeyEventHandler(DataGridcell_PreviewKeyDown);
            cell.PreviewKeyDown -= previewKeyDownHandler;
            cell.PreviewKeyDown += previewKeyDownHandler;
        }
    }

    void DataGridCell_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridCell cell = (DataGridCell)sender;

        dgrdInvoice.CurrentCell = new DataGridCellInfo((DataGridCell)sender);
        dgrdInvoice.BeginEdit();

        Debug.WriteLine("got focus" + cell.ToString());
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    void DataGridcell_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridCell cell = (DataGridCell)sender;
        DataGridCellsPresenter cellsPresenter = (DataGridCellsPresenter)DataGridCellsPresenter
                                                                            .ItemsControlFromItemContainer(cell);
        int cellCount = cellsPresenter.Items.Count;
        int currCellIndex = dgrdInvoice.CurrentColumn.DisplayIndex;

        DataGridRow rowContainer = (DataGridRow)DataGridCellsPresenter.ContainerFromElement(dgrdInvoice, cell);

        DataGridCell nextCell;

        if (e.Key == Key.Enter || e.Key == Key.Escape)
        {
            if (currCellIndex < cellCount - 1)
            {
                nextCell = GetCell(dgrdInvoice, rowContainer, currCellIndex + 1); // get next cell
            }
            else
            {
                currCellIndex = -1;

                nextCell = GetCell(dgrdInvoice, GetNextRow(dgrdInvoice, rowContainer), currCellIndex + 1); // get next cell
            }

            if(e.Key == Key.Escape)
            {
                dgrdInvoice.CancelEdit();
            }

            e.Handled = true;
            nextCell.Focus();
            dgrdInvoice.BeginEdit();
        }
    }

    #region DataGrid Navigation Helper

    public static T FindVisualChild<T>(DependencyObject obj) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);
            if (child != null && child is T)
                return (T)child;
            else
            {
                T childOfChild = FindVisualChild<T>(child);
                if (childOfChild != null)
                    return childOfChild;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static DataGridRow GetNextRow(System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid dataGrid, DataGridRow currRow)
    {
        DataGridRow nextRow = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < dataGrid.Items.Count; ++i)
        {
            DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);

            if (row.Equals(currRow))
            {
                nextRow = (DataGridRow)dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i + 1);
                if (nextRow.IsNewItem)
                    nextRow = (DataGridRow)dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(0);

                break;
            }
        }

        return nextRow;
    }

    public static DataGridCell GetCell(System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid dataGrid, DataGridRow rowContainer, int column)
    {
        if (rowContainer != null)
        {
            DataGridCellsPresenter presenter = FindVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(rowContainer);
            if (presenter == null)
            {
                /* if the row has been virtualized away, call its ApplyTemplate() method 
                 * to build its visual tree in order for the DataGridCellsPresenter
                 * and the DataGridCells to be created */
                rowContainer.ApplyTemplate();
                presenter = FindVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(rowContainer);
            }
            if (presenter != null)
            {
                DataGridCell cell = presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(column) as DataGridCell;
                if (cell == null)
                {
                    /* bring the column into view
                     * in case it has been virtualized away */
                    dataGrid.ScrollIntoView(rowContainer, dataGrid.Columns[column]);
                    cell = presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(column) as DataGridCell;
                }
                return cell;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    #endregion
```

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to mention that i work in MVVM Approche, so no code behind, right ? Your Code already exits in my Behavior above, but does not work. When the cell containing ACB gain Focus, i have to press any Key again to pass in edit mode.

Comment: @HabibGherairi The code which I posted works perfectly fine. Cell enters edit mode when it receives focus without pressing any key. Click a cell and press tab to go to next cell.

Comment: Do not forget that the cell in question contains a AutocompleteBox inside. That is the problem. As you say, the first simple cell works fine, but the one that wrap the ACB need another keypress

Comment: Thanks for editing your answer, but sorry it still does'nt work. I Don't have a problem with navigation between cells, the behavior called "DataGridEnterKeyBehavior" works perfectly, but i have a problem with Autocomplete. I want to enter directly in edit mode when i focus it.

Comment: When you focus in a cell, you want AutoComplete to show, so that you can see some entries, select one and that selected values goes into Cell. Is it so ? I only demonstrated your Enter key scenario and navigation between cells. I didnt use AutoComplete.

Comment: No, When i select the cell containing AutoComplete, it did not entre in edit mode. I have to press Enter key to do that.

Comment: Have you used my code ? And do you face problems only for cell containing AutoComplete ? With rest of the cells, as soon as cell gets focus, editing is enabled automatically.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91416/discussion-between-habib-gherairi-and-anjumskhan).